# foundation accordion stop toggle

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, accordion

I am trying to make the accordion work so if you click the first one and it shows, then if you click the second one, i dont want the first one to close. I want it so if you want the first one to close, you click it again.

Here is an example of how i want it to work. look at the sidebar on the left
http://www.houseoffraser.co.uk/mens+watches/2031,default,sc.html?srule=price-desc&fix&spcl

Here is my code

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
              <dd>
                <a href="#panel1">Accordion 1</a>
                <div id="panel1" class="content active">
                ffjkfkfkjfkj
                </div>
              </dd>
              <dd>
                <a href="#panel2">Accordion 2</a>
                <div id="panel2" class="content">
                  Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </dd>
              <dd>
                <a href="#panel3">Accordion 3</a>
                <div id="panel3" class="content">
                  Panel 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
              </dd>
            </dl>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the normal JS Foundation event with your custom Jquery script

```
$('.accordion dd > a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});
```